# Zend Framework - Login error - Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have an error with the user login

```
Error: The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
#0 /home/cari/library/Zend/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php(369): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_authenticateQuerySelect(Object(Zend_Db_Select))
#1 /home/cari/library/Zend/Auth.php(117): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->authenticate()
#2 /home/cari/application/controllers/AuthController.php(49): Zend_Auth->authenticate(Object(Cari_Auth_Adapter_Local))
#3 /home/cari/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): AuthController->identifyAction()
#4 /home/cari/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('identifyAction')
#5 /home/cari/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#6 /home/cari/application/bootstrap.php(113): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#7 /home/cari/webroot/index.php(6): Bootstrap->runApp()
#8 {main}
```

ZF version is 1.11.6, MySQL server version is  5.5.37, running on ubuntu 12.04 with php 5.3.10.

It's a legacy application, so that's the reason of having a so old version of Zend Framework.
Any help on that?

Thanks

Comment: Show us code surrounding 49th line of AuthController and Cari_Auth_Adapter_Local class content.

Comment: solved: downgraded the version of ubuntu box to lucid, in order to have mysql-server-5.1.
Thanks anyway :)